# Hide Selected Cell from the Table - Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, tableview

I have a list with 4 objects of **places** that I query from my  **Realm** database.

```
Optional(Results<Place> <0x7feaaea447c0> (
    [0] Place {
        name = Daniel Webster Highway;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.72073329999999;
        lon = -71.44301460000001;
    },
    [1] Place {
        name = District Avenue;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.48354969999999;
        lon = -71.2102486;
    },
    [2] Place {
        name = Gorham Street;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.62137479999999;
        lon = -71.30538779999999;
    },
    [3] Place {
        name = Route de HHF;
        country = Haiti;
        lat = 18.6401311;
        lon = -74.1203939;
    }
))
```

I'm trying to hide the selected one.

Ex. When I click on `Daniel Webster Highway`, I don't want that to show on my list.

[image]

How would one go above and do that in Swift 4 ?

---

## Code

```
//
//  PlaceDetailVC.swift
//  Memorable Places
//
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import RealmSwift

class PlaceDetailVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var placesTable: UITableView!

    var selectedPlace : Place = Place()
    var selectedTrip : Trip = Trip()
    
    var distances = [ String ]()
    var places : Results<Place>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        address.text = selectedPlace.name
    
        //register xib file
        placesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "PlaceDetailCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell")
    
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        load()
        
        if selectedPlace != nil && places != nil {
            
            for i in 0..<places!.count {
                
                let latitude = Double(places![i].lat)
                let longitude = Double(places![i].lon)
                
                let currentLatitude = Double(selectedPlace.lat)
                let currentLongitude = Double(selectedPlace.lon)
                
                //print(latitude,longitude,currentLatitude,currentLongitude)
                
                let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                let currentCoordinate = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)
                
                let distanceInMeters = coordinate.distance(from: currentCoordinate) // result is in meters
                let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609.344
                
                distances.append(String(format: "%.2f", distanceInMiles))
                
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - CRUD functions
    
    
    //Read
    func load() {
        places  = selectedTrip.places.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
        //print(places,"<<<")
        placesTable.reloadData()
        
    }

    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Table View Datasource
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return places?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell", for: indexPath)
         as! CustomPlaceDetailCell
        
        if selectedPlace.name != nil {
           
            cell.address.text = (places![indexPath.row]["name"] as! String)
            cell.distance.text = distances[indexPath.row]

        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Table View Delegate
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        activePlace = indexPath.row
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: You need to update the array containing the values. Either you remove it, or since it seems that you replace it with an "image", just "mark it", reload that row, check if it's "marked" and dequeue the correct cell or the "normal one".

Comment: You should edit your question with the code you use for displaying those results in the table view, otherwise it's quite hard to give an exact answer with code.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I apologize, totally didn't think of that. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the index of the selected row from placesVC to your PlaceDetailVC and in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == passedIndex {
        return 0
    }

    return 70
}
```

set the cell height to 0 to hide the cell.

Comment: I like the way you thinking. We don't have to remove anything from the array at all or maintain another array. Adding an if-check with 1 line, done,  That's kind of cool;

Comment: Works in first try, although I notice 1 caveat. Seems like it still display the distance value about 2 pixels. See this image : https://i.imgur.com/itaMyRd.png

Comment: Is your PlaceDetailCell build with constraints? Show me how it looks if you selected the second row

Comment: If I click the second row, I got this : https://i.imgur.com/MVCwtAm.png

Comment: Weired. Ok so the easy fix would be in cellForRowAt use if indexPath.row == passedIndex { cell.distance.isHidden = true } else { cell.distance.isHidden = false} but this is very ugly. It could be that the 2 pixel are shown because of wrong constraints or because of the seperators.

Answer (score 2):

```
var distances = [ String ]()
var places : Results<Place>?
```

Then in `tableView(_:cellForRow:)`

```
cell.address.text = (places![indexPath.row]["name"] as! String)
cell.distance.text = distances[indexPath.row]
```

Just don't do that. These info need to be synchronized.

Instead, use another class/struct, or an extension which will hold the distance and the place.

```
var array: [PlaceModel]
struct PlaceModel {
    let place: Place
    let distance: Double //You can use String, but that's bad habit
    //Might want to add the "image link" also?
}
```

In `load()`:

```
array.removeAll()
let tempPlaces = selectedTrip.places.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)
for aPlace in tempPlaces {
    let distance = //Calculate distance for aPlace
    array.append(PlaceModel(place: aPlace, distance: distance)
}
```

Now, in `tableView(_:cellForRow:)`:

```
let aPlaceModel = array[indexPath.row]
if activePlace == indexPath {
    let cell = tableView.dequeue...
    //Use cellWithImage for that place
    return cell
} else {
    let cell = tableView.dequeue...
    cell.address.text = aPlaceModel.place.name
    cell.distance.text = aPlaceModel.distance
    return cell
}
```

And keep that logic wherever you want, if the heightForRow if needed (if you want for instance that all your images be at 80pt but the rest at 44pts, etc.

In `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`, add `tableView.reloadData()`, or better `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath] with: .automatic)`

NB: Code not tested, might not compile, but you should get the idea.