# Display Sorted Result on a Table - Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

## I have

places that contain these contents

```
print(places)

Optional(Results<Place> <0x109526f30> (
    [0] Place {
        name = 127 Pine St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.63341130000001;
        lon = -71.33169049999999;
    },
    [1] Place {
        name = 138 B St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.6285025;
        lon = -71.3288776;
    },
    [2] Place {
        name = 16 Bagley Ave;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.6344084;
        lon = -71.3378318;
    },
    [3] Place {
        name = 27 Lane St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.6346452;
        lon = -71.32436559999999;
    },
    [4] Place {
        name = 39 Cosgrove St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.61964890000001;
        lon = -71.3031683;
    },
    [5] Place {
        name = 48 Houghton St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.6252232;
        lon = -71.3243308;
    },
    [6] Place {
        name = 49 Coral St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.6359846;
        lon = -71.32655780000002;
    },
    [7] Place {
        name = 59 Marriner St;
        country = United States;
        lat = 42.622121;
        lon = -71.31365679999999;
    }
)) <<<
```

I also have another array that I maintain in the memory that look like this

```
 print(distances)
 ["1.74", "1.45", "2.04", "1.50", "0.00", "1.15", "1.64", "0.56"]
```

---

## Result

My end result look like this.

[image]

---

## Code

This is how I render this table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customPlaceDetailCell", for: indexPath)
     as! CustomPlaceDetailCell

    if selectedPlace.name != nil {

        cell.address.text = (places![indexPath.row]["name"] as! String)
        cell.distance.text = distances[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row == activePlace {
            cell.address.isHidden = true
            cell.distance.isHidden = true
        }

    }

    return cell
}
```

## I want

to show my result sorted by distance closer to farther

---

Note : my distance is not as part of my places object. I calculated them during the run time.

How would one and go about and do this ?

Comment: Make the distance part of the data model used to populate the table. You only want one array, not two.

Comment: Just sort the array?

Comment: @rmaddy distance between each point is calculate on the fly, not store in the database. I don't see the need to store it.

Comment: It didn't say anything about storing the distance. You need a separate data model used for the table view. Populate it with a combination of the data you load from the database and data you calculate at runtime.

Comment: Got it, I see your point now, I need to find a way to merge my data model into 1 array somehow, and sort that array;

Comment: Use `CLLocation` and its distance math skills.

Comment: @vadian I have no problems getting the distances :) the issue is sorting while have 2 arrays.

Comment: As rmaddy suggests don't use two arrays. Use a computed property in your model for the distance.

Comment: @rmaddy Even if I want to take your advice, how would I start ? both of the array seems to have same index, but different dataType. How do I start ? Do u mind get me started with a few lines of starter sample code ?

Comment: You could use zip to combine the arrays into one, then sort the combined arrays. You could add a property distance to each place that is ephemeral and sort that.

Comment: I told you to use only one array on your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53174828/hide-selected-cell-from-the-table-swift4/53175275#53175275 As you can see, if you sort `places`, you need to sort the same way `distances`. Also, there is plenty question about sorting and you don't show any tries.

Comment: @kyo The answer that Larme just linked (from 5 hours ago) is exactly what I'm talking about. Never have two arrays for your table. Create one array with the data for the table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating distances between points is expensive. You should only do it once, or if your data changes.
Sorting is expensive. You should only do it once, or if your data changes.

Trying to sort 2 different arrays is a bad idea.

Sorting compares the items in an array many times. You need a place to save the distances so that you can sort your places.

Make your `Place` object a `Struct` with methods and properties, not a `Dictionary`.

I would add a computed distance property to your array. Also add a an `internalDistance` property that is an `Optional`.

Make the computed distance property's getter return the `internalDistance` if it's not nil, or compute the distance, save it to the `internalDistance`, and return it if it's nil.

If you change the destination point, loop through the array of places and nil out all the `internalDistance` variables, then re-sort the array of Places.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be one possibility.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated : Bool){
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
 placeArray = zip(places,distance).sorted{$0.1<$1.1}.map{$0.0}
}
```

`cell.address.text = (placeArray![indexPath.row]["name"] as! String)`

---

If you want another method may be faster, you can sort the distance like this:

`placeArray = distance.enumerated().sorted{$0.element<$1.element}.map{places[$0.offset]}`

This needs one sort of distance as index.

Comment: I tried to place it in my viewDidLoad() after both variables available. I got this : https://i.imgur.com/ZJUGW8s.png

Comment: could Result<Place> have some methods, like places.array or places.objects? to return an array type.  Is that Core-Data?

Comment: let me try your second one;

Comment: Maybe you need an init method to convert the array result like in the updated one.

Comment: I've tried `places = Results<Place>?.init(zip(places!,distances).sorted{$0.1<$1.1}.map{$0.0})` , I got  https://i.imgur.com/dxZikfZ.png

Comment: how about `zip(places,distance)` only?

Comment: Just that will be success, but I got this : https://i.imgur.com/oBVK970.png

Comment: So the sort  is ok. Maybe you don't need to wrap the array back to Result<T>. You can give it to a new `let  placeArray:  [Place] =  zip(places!,distance).sorted{$0.1<$1.1}.map{$0.0}` and use it in the tableview datasource as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: It seems to compile, can update your answer with the correct syntax for cellForRowAt function ? https://i.imgur.com/OgBCo9O.png

Comment: When I print them out to test, the distance data/value is not part of `placeArray` : https://i.imgur.com/wNE6iUq.png How's come ?

Comment: This is not a good solution. `cellForRow` is called many, many times. This code would have you zip and sort the same data over and over and over each time when you only need one value each time. Create a single array at the start. Sort it once. Then `cellForRow` doesn't need to do any work other than get the one specific value it needs from the already sorted array.

Comment: last one `map{$0.0}` only choose the place not with the distance. because distance is in $0.1. if you use map{$0.1}, you will get the distance array.

Comment: placeArray is better to  put outside the (cellForRow) May be in ViewdidLoad() as long as it's an instance var.

Comment: Zipping and sorting the arrays to fill each cell? No, that's bad. You want your code that provides cells to be fast.

Comment: Nope, just put it in the DataReceived once. Not to put in cellForRowAt()